# "No Activity found to handle Intent" while emailing data

Tags: android-intent

I am trying to mail data using this code:

```
email = (Button) findViewById(R.id.enail);
    email.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent emailIntent = new Intent(
                    android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            emailIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
                    new String[] { "" });
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_CC, "");
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_BCC, "");
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
                    "Playlist Details");
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(Detail));
            emailIntent.setType("text/html");
            startActivity(emailIntent);

        }
    });
```

But it throws the following error:

```
07-17 12:31:33.438: E/AndroidRuntime(498): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-17 12:31:33.438: E/AndroidRuntime(498): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.SEND (has extras) }
07-17 12:31:33.438: E/AndroidRuntime(498):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1408)
07-17 12:31:33.438: E/AndroidRuntime(498):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1378)
07-17 12:31:33.438: E/AndroidRuntime(498):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2817)
07-17 12:31:33.438: E/AndroidRuntime(498):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2923)
07-17 12:31:33.438: E/AndroidRuntime(498):  at com.playlist.ViewPlayList$3.onClick(ViewPlayList.java:93)
07-17 12:31:33.438: E/AndroidRuntime(498):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
07-17 12:31:33.438: E/AndroidRuntime(498):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
07-17 12:31:33.438: E/AndroidRuntime(498):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-17 12:31:33.438: E/AndroidRuntime(498):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-17 12:31:33.438: E/AndroidRuntime(498):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-17 12:31:33.438: E/AndroidRuntime(498):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-17 12:31:33.438: E/AndroidRuntime(498):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-17 12:31:33.438: E/AndroidRuntime(498):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-17 12:31:33.438: E/AndroidRuntime(498):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-17 12:31:33.438: E/AndroidRuntime(498):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-17 12:31:33.438: E/AndroidRuntime(498):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please help me.

Comment: Do you have required permissions?

Comment: what OS version are you using to test, and what device are you testing on?

Comment: and what exactly contains `Details` ?

Comment: Have the same error on my nexus 5 with android 5.1.1. Have gmail app, and default email application. Gmail in active use... What i do wrong?

Comment: Using `Intent.ACTION_SENDTO` fixed it for me

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I tested this on my device, and the code works perfectly. And I testet this code on an emulator, too, and it crashed. The problem is that the OS didn't find any activities which can handle this `ACTION_SEND`. Surround this kind of code all the time with a `try/catch`, since you can not be sure if there exists such an activity that can handle your intent. And try to install at least one app that can handle the `ACTION_SEND`, then try again, and see if it works for you.

Comment: instead of surrounding it by a try catch, you can and you should just check how many activities there are that can handle the intent...
for example you can do:
PackageManager packageManager = getActivity().getPackageManager();
if (intent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
  // there is an activity that can handle it
} else
// there is no activity that can handle it :)

Answer (score 62):

Call the `StartActivity` method in the following way:

```
    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(
                        android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                emailIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
                        new String[] { "" });
                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_CC, "");
                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_BCC, "");
                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
                        "Playlist Details");
                emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(Detail));
                emailIntent.setType("text/html");

// FOLLOWING STATEMENT CHECKS WHETHER THERE IS ANY APP THAT CAN HANDLE OUR EMAIL INTENT 
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent,
                        "Send Email Using: "));
```

If System do not find any eamil application, A nice Dialog will be shown:

[image]

---

*I know that i am answering an old question, but maybe it can help someone.*

Comment: This is a GREAT solution to this problem. Thank you!

Comment: Great, but emailIntent.setType(); is being used twice :)

Answer (score 7):

try to use this for better practice showing a message to the user to setup a mail application.

```
try{

// you email code here

} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
// show message to user
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes problem was in emulator because it was not configured any email in emulator,
if any one find this problem please configure email in your emulator, to do this

select email from application menu and follow the steps.

Answer (score 4):

There's another subtle cause for this exception to occur.

My app sends an email in two different conditions. One condition I set the To: field - it required Intent.ACTION_SENDTO

But Intent.ACTION_SENDTO causes the described exeption in my other condition where To: is not supplied. In that condition Intent.ACTION_SEND was required.

Answer (score 2):

Also `intent.resolveActivity(activity.getPackageManager())` can be used.
The `resolveActivity` method checks whether exists `Activity` to handle `intent` or not.

Code example to call from Activity :

```
if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivity(intent);
} else {
    Toast.makeText(this, "No app to send email. Please install at least one", 
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

And also check it out : https://medium.com/better-programming/the-imperfect-android-send-email-action-59610dfd1c2d