# Try to resolve ActivityNotFoundException

Tags: java, android, android-intent, google-plus

I try to share a post on google+ but I obtain this Exception. The Activity that creates the Exception is ExampleActivity and this is its code:

```
public class ExampleActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener,
            ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener {
        private static final String TAG = "ExampleActivity";
        private static final int REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR = 9000;

        private ProgressDialog mConnectionProgressDialog;
        private PlusClient mPlusClient;
        private ConnectionResult mConnectionResult;

        @Override//onCreate
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_example);
            mPlusClient = new PlusClient.Builder(this, this, this)
                    .setVisibleActivities("http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity","http://schemas.google.com/BuyActivity")
                    .build();
            // Progress bar to be displayed if the connection failure is not resolved.
            mConnectionProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);


     mConnectionProgressDialog.setMessage("Signing in...");
        Button shareButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.share_button);
        shareButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
              // Launch the Google+ share dialog with attribution to your app.
              Intent shareIntent = new PlusShare.Builder()
                  .setType("text/plain")
                  .setText("Welcome to 

the Google+ platform.")
                      .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://developers.google.com/+/"))
                      .getIntent();

                  startActivityForResult(shareIntent, 0);
                }
            });

        }

        @Override//onStart
        protected void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            mPlusClient.connect();
        }

        @Override//onStop
        protected void onStop() {
            super.onStop();
            mPlusClient.disconnect();
        }

        @Override// onConnectionFailed
        public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
          if (mConnectionProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
            // The user clicked the sign-in button already. Start to resolve
            // connection errors. Wait until onConnected() to dismiss the
            // connection dialog.
            if (result.hasResolution()) {
              try {
                       result.startResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR);
               } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                       mPlusClient.connect();
               }
            }
          }
          // Save the result and resolve the connection failure upon a user click.
          mConnectionResult = result;
        }

        @Override //onActivityResult
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode, Intent intent) {
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR && responseCode == RESULT_OK) {
                mConnectionResult = null;
                mPlusClient.connect();
            }
        }

    //    @Override
    //    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    //        String accountName = mPlusClient.getAccountName();
    //        Toast.makeText(this, accountName + " is connected.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    //    }

        @Override //onDisconnected
        public void onDisconnected() {
              String accountName = mPlusClient.getAccountName();
              Toast.makeText(this, accountName + " is connected.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override//onConnected
        public void onConnected() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {


        }
    }
```

This is the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.applicazionescienza"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="11"
            android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <activity
                android:name="com.example.applicazionescienza.Menu"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:launchMode="singleInstance" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name="com.example.applicazionescienza.Informazioni"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_informazioni" >
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name="com.example.applicazionescienza.Regolamento"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_regolamento" >
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name="com.example.applicazionescienza.Gioca"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_gioca" >
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name="com.example.applicazionescienza.Livello"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_livello" >
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name="com.example.applicazionescienza.Punteggio"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_punteggio" >
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name="com.example.applicazionescienza.TwitterActivity"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_twitter"
                android:launchMode="singleInstance" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                    <data
                        android:host="casa"
                        android:scheme="app" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name="com.example.applicazionescienza.FacebookActivity"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_facebook" >
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name="com.example.applicazionescienza.ExampleActivity"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_example" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </application>
    </manifest>
```

The Exception say: No activity found to handle Intent(act=android.intent.action.SEND....
Someone can help me?

Comment: Please post properly formatted code. Be kind towards us, we are here to help you.

Comment: Post the complete text of the exception please

Comment: Are you checking this code in device or emulator?? Please check this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11517563/no-activity-found-to-handle-intent-while-emailing-data

Answer (score 0):

Try and `clean` the project, uninstall your app from device and reinstall.