# TextView performClick() doesn't click a link

Tags: android, textview

I have a `TextView` with `android:autoLink="all"`:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:text="abcdefgh@def.com"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:autoLink="all" />
```

For some reason I want to open a link set in `android:text` (it may be phone number, email, etc.). When I run an application, a `performClick()` doesn't open the link.

```
TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.text);
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
textView.performClick();
```

`Linkify.addLinks(buffer, Linkify.ALL);` and some others don't help.

**UPDATE**

Thank you for replies. Show my code after receiving 3 answers. I use API 19, 25 emulators and device (API 21). Sadly, nothing works.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:text="abcdefgh@def.com"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:autoLink="web|email|phone" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView text = findViewById(R.id.text);
        int mask = Linkify.ALL;
        Linkify.addLinks(text, mask);
        text.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        text.performClick();
    }
}
```

Comment: set TextView clickable in xml

Comment: @Danger, thanks, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Just use this `android:autoLink="web"` in your xml and nothing else. It worked for me. And let me know if it works

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't help me, please, see an update.

Answer (score 1):

Use `autoLink="web"`.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:text="abcdefgh@def.com"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:autoLink="web" />
```

To do it programmatically, use `view.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());` in your code and make sure you **do not** have `android:autoLink="web"` in your XML layout.

Example:

```
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    text.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

**EDIT**

Use `android:linksClickable="true"` also. It might work. Also make sure to use either `autoLink` or `setMovementMethod`. Do not use both of them together.

**EDIT 2**

I realise you want to use `performClick()` on your textView. Although there aren't many examples for `android.widget.TextView.performClick()`, which means the method is either unpopular or old. However it can be implemented like this:

```
TextView text ;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Text1);
    text.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View arg0) {
      Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://google.com"));
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

This matches with your requirement. Check if it works.

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't help me, please, see an update.

Comment: I tried to add `android:linksClickable="true"` and remove `text.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());`, but it didn't help, sorry.

Comment: Thanks. Similar answer offered @PAWAN LAKHOTIA. I think if add some actions on `onClick` event (for URL, email, phone) it will work.

Answer (score 1):

we need to override performClick():

```
@Override
 public boolean performClick() {
  // Calls the super implementation, which generates an AccessibilityEvent
        // and calls the onClick() listener on the view, if any
        super.performClick();

        // Handle the action for the custom click here

        return true;
 }
```

Comment: Sorry, where can I override it?

Comment: sorry, do this-    `add this android:onClick="onClick"`   then You must also implement View.OnClickListener and in onClick method can use intent    Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
           intent.setData(Uri.parse("https://youraddress.com"));    
            startActivity(intent);              I have tested this,it worked fine

Comment: or to click on a piece of the text (not the whole TextView), you can use Html or Linkify (both create links that open urls, though, not a callback in the app).

Comment: Probably it's a good solution, but it fails with exception (`startActivity` line): "Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=youraddress.com }".

Comment: To solve it, we may write a correct URL like: `intent.setData(Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/abc/"));`.

Comment: Change your answer, please, so that I could accept it. I mean write `textView.setOnClickListener` with URL, email, phone behaviour, also see exception catch for them (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5882656/no-activity-found-to-handle-intent-android-intent-action-view, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11517563/no-activity-found-to-handle-intent-while-emailing-data, etc).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the thing you are trying to achieve is not possible. Based on documentation of textView.performClick():

> Call this view's OnClickListener, if it is defined

Since you haven't defined any onClickListener, the approaches won't work.

The workaround would be to define your custom onClickListener and try to parse the URI programatically to trigger appropriate `Intent.ACTION_VIEW`

Comment: Oh! Thanks. So much time has been lost. I will create a listener as PAWAN LAKHOTIA and Abhi offered.

Comment: Yes. You can create a listener. But be careful, the approaches mentioned might not work for link type `PHONE_NUMMBER`. You might need to parse the content carefully and trigger `ACTION_VIEW` or `ACTION_CALL`

Comment: Great! Enjoy coding